# Facebook PHP SDK 5.0 - Posting to group

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been stumped for a while now.  I'm attempting to write myself a small app to automatically post to a number of groups that I am members of in FB.  I'm a PHP novice, but this is about my strongest skill set for what FB allows in terms of access that I can tell.  So far, I CAN post to my own wall no problem but once I try and post to my own FB testing group I'm stumped.  Here is my code so far...

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';    
require 'src/config.php';
require 'src/facebook.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $config['App_ID'],
  'app_secret' => $config['App_Secret'],
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
  ]);

$linkData = [
  'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
  'message' => 'Test post to my feed.',
  ];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/{group_id}/feed', $linkData, $config['Access_Token']);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
?>
```

Currently the error that this is generating is:
  Graph returned an error: (#200) Insufficient permission to post to target on behalf of the viewer

I have made the app Public and generated the access token with manage_pages and publish_pages.  Unfortunately I'm out of ideas as of this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is telling you it's a facebook problem. Either you're not authing the account correctly, your facebook account hasn't given the application permission(more than likely your error here) TO post on its behalf, or you don't have permission to post to the group.

Comment: Just double checked that the app has permissions to post on my behalf.  I can post to the group interactively from FB so it's not permissions to post to the group either.  I'm not sure about "authing the account correctly"...

Comment: It is not possible to posts to groups that you are not admin of

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I figured out my problem at this point.  It was that I had to go into the App Settings in my FB user account and change my App from "Only Me" to Public.  Once I did that I was able to post to my groups.  Next will be to figure out how to post into the proper fields for a "Sell Something" type of post and then to test it in groups that I'm not an admin of.

I figure it has to be possible to post into non-admin groups since there are a number of services out there for FB auto-posting and they have to get around it somehow.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to post to non admin groups without going through the tedious rigmarole of submitting  app for review?

Comment: As suggested by @Scott, sometimes "Only Me" to public is what we need to do. And for me, I was able to do it while generating User token. But I only was able to fix when I once clear all permission -> saved -> changed permission again. Hope this will be helpful for someone.