# Posting on facebook group using facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know whether it is possible to post on facebook group using facebook page with graph API or not.

I have been struggling finding solutions for this.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336199/facebook-php-sdk-5-0-posting-to-group may give some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that that’s **not** currently possible.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v9.0/group/feed#publish says the requirements include that a *user* access token is used, and that the permission `publish_to_groups` must be granted, and the description of that permission also uses phrasing that indicates pretty clearly, that this is supposed to be used to publish as a user, not a page.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/publish_to_groups